# SQL Query Common Value after count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to know how to solve this problem, I have these two tables:

```
TABLE FRIENDSHIP
Name | Friend
--------------
John | Mark
Peter | Paul
Simon | Mary

TABLE SCHOOL
Name | School
--------------
John | SchoolA
Mark | SchoolA
Peter | SchoolB
Paul | SchoolC
Simon | SchoolC
Mary | SchoolD
```

How do I select those people that are friends but do not attend the same school?
I thought to select first schools that have a count of <2 and then compare the name of these people with the names in FRIENDSHIP table (comparing both columns name and friend). How do I transfor this into a query? Sorry for being a newbie..

It should return me something like:

```
Name | Friend
---------------
Peter | Paul
Simon | Mary
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try joining the `SCHOOL` table to the `FRIENDSHIP` twice, once for each friend in the pair.  Then you can restrict your result set by retaining only friend pairs whose respective schools are *not* the same.

```
SELECT f.Name, f.Friend
FROM FRIENDSHIP f INNER JOIN SCHOOL s1 ON f.Name = s1.Name
INNER JOIN SCHOOL s2 ON f.Friend = s2.Name
WHERE s1.School <> s2.School
```

Here is a working demo of this query using your sample data:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34e499/1)

Comment: I have tried your code but it gives me an empty output, I created the FRIENDSHIP TABLE with both name and friend as primary key, is this the problem or what?

Comment: @AlessiaFerroni The query works fine in the fiddle.  And the other 2 answers should also work.  My suspicion is that there is a problem on your end.

Comment: I have posted the exact tables in my question, the school and friends were just an example. Could the sqlite version i'm using be a problem?

Comment: Try adapting one of the answers given here to your real table, and then come back if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Did you notice that data in Founder column does not completely match data in colleague?

Comment: I have tried:select name, colleague from collaboration C INNER JOIN restaurant_founder as RF1 ON C.name = RF1.restaurant INNER JOIN restaurant_founder as RF2 ON C.colleague = RF2.restaurant WHERE RF1.restaurant <> RF2.restaurant;    ************  select * from collaboration where (select rf2.restaurant from restaurant_founder rf2 where collaboration.name = rf2.founder) != (select rf1.restaurant from restaurant_founder rf1 where collaboration.name =rf1.founder);
 ******* both are not working (empty output)

Comment: If I disable the columns it gives the the full text and I still get an empty output.

Comment: As @Adish mentioned, there might be something wrong with your data.  All the queries given as answers look right, and two have been tested on SQL Fiddle with test data.

Comment: I tried another method but it does only half of the job. This is the code: select founder from (select founder, restaurant, count(restaurant) as "X" from restaurant_founder group by restaurant) where (X=1); **** it finds only one person in the friendship relationship.

Comment: Please recreate your tables with clean data and try again.  This is really the best anyone will be able to do for you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT F.Name, F.Friend
FROM Friendship F
INNER JOIN School AS School1 ON F.Name = School1.Name
INNER JOIN School AS School2 ON F.Friend = School2.Name
WHERE School1.School <> School2.School
```

EDIT: modified according to actual schema

```
SELECT C.Name, C.Colleague
FROM Collaboration C
INNER JOIN restaurant_founder AS rf1 ON C.Name = rf1.founder
INNER JOIN restaurant_founder AS rf2 ON C.Colleague = rf2.founder
WHERE rf1.restaurant <> rf2.restaurant
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it gives me an empty output, I created the FRIENDSHIP TABLE with both name and friend as primary key, is this the problem or what?

Comment: That should not be a problem. Can you run a select * on both the tables and paste your output here?

Comment: I'll post this in the question since it is not code formatted.

Comment: Data in the founder column is truncated. that is the issue

Comment: We can not answer the question Why is it truncated. You will have to ask the person responsible for inserting/updating data to this table. If you have the insert/update queries, I can take a look. An example of truncated data is Marco Tafur instead of Marco Tafuri

Comment: Okay I have tried to disable the columns so that it gives the the full text but the output is still empty

Comment: What do you mean by disable the columns? You will not get correct output till your data is correct.

Comment: If i open the database and then i don't run ".mode column" when i run select * table, the values in the columns are correct and not truncated.

Comment: If you are saying that you see "Marco Tafuri" when you run select * table, but we see "Marco Tafur" when you paste it here, it beats me.

Comment: I have updated the output of select when I don't use mode column. Have a look at it.

Comment: What are your table and column names? I will modify my query to suit your schema.

Comment: table name is: collaboration (name|colleague) and restaurant_founder(founder|restaurant).

Comment: I have added the modified query to the answer. Please try now

Comment: I tried it but it gives me all the values in collaboration table.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select * from friend f
where (select s2.school from school s2
       where f.name = s2.name) != (select s1.school from school s1
                                  where f.friend = s1.name)
```

Here is a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee760/2)

Comment: I have tried your code but it gives me an empty output, I created the FRIENDSHIP TABLE with both name and friend as primary key, is this the problem or what?

Comment: Check the demo link, it has sqlfiddle. I have created the schema there and it gives the correct result.

Comment: is it that i use sqlite the problem? i posted in the question what i get from select * from the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 type of people on your example.

Let's call the first one as `Name` and the second one as `Friend`.

Both `Name` and `Friend` has `School`.

We need to compare that their `School` is different, so we need to get their `School` first.

Let's get `School` for `Name` by joining `Friend.Name` to `School.Name`

```
SELECT f.Name, School, f.Friend 
FROM Friend AS f
INNER JOIN School AS s ON f.Name = s.Name
```

Now let's get `School` for `Friend` by joining `Friend.Friend` to `School.Name`

```
SELECT Friend, School 
FROM Friend AS f
INNER JOIN School AS s ON f.Friend = s.Name
```

Now we got result for `SchoolOfName` and `SchoolOfFriend`, let's join them by `Friend` of `SchoolOfName` and `Friend` of `SchoolOfFriend`

And also, `School` of `SchoolOfName` should not be equal to `School` of `SchoolofFriend`

```
SELECT  Name
       ,SchoolOfName.School AS SchoolOfName
       ,SchoolOfName.Friend
       ,SchoolOfFriend.School AS SchoolOfFriend
FROM (
    SELECT f.Name, School, f.Friend 
    FROM Friend AS f
    INNER JOIN School AS s ON f.Name = s.Name
) AS SchoolOfName
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Friend, School 
    FROM Friend AS f
    INNER JOIN School AS s ON f.Friend = s.Name
) AS SchoolOfFriend
ON SchoolOfName.Friend = SchoolOfFriend.Friend
AND NOT SchoolOfName.School = SchoolOfFriend.School
```